# Fetching movie information from the TMDB API with python

Tags: python

I am trying to get information about a movie using the TMDB API with python. I have written a script to pull information I want such as the movie title, tagline, genres and the poster image. This is the script I currently have to pull the information I need.

```
import requests
import os
from dotenv import find_dotenv, load_dotenv 

load_dotenv(find_dotenv())
API_KEY = os.getenv("API_KEY")

BASE_URL = "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/27205"
endpoint = f"{BASE_URL}?api_key={API_KEY}"

r = requests.get(endpoint)
data = r.json()
data.keys()

print (data["title"])
print (data["tagline"])
print (data["genres"])
print (data["poster_path"])
```

Using that script, my output is then displayed as:

Inception
Your mind is the scene of the crime.
[{'id': 28, 'name': 'Action'}, {'id': 878, 'name': 'Science Fiction'}, {'id': 12, 'name': 'Adventure'}]
/edv5CZvWj09upOsy2Y6IwDhK8bt.jpg

It fetches the name and tagline in the formate I want, but I want the genres to be shown as a list: (Action, Science Fiction, Adventure). I want it to be displayed without the ID's. And for the poster image, I would want it to be displayed as a url so I can actually access the image. Does anyone know how I can fix this? Thanks

Comment: Yep, for the genres it's just `print(", ".join([genre["name"] for genre in data["genres"]])`

Comment: I am getting an error. Is there anything else I would need to add to the code ?

Comment: @Lotus you will have to be more specific about the error : what is the error message and the traceback you got ?

Comment: @Lenormju when I change the line of code print (data["genres"]) to print(", ".join([genre["name"] for genre in data["genres"]]). I then get an error for the next line which says " print (data["poster_path"])" and the error message is , line 18
    print (data ["poster_path"])
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments and the solution provided by @Jack Deeth :

```py
fake_data = {
    "title": "Inception",
    "tagline": "Your mind is the scene of the crime.",
    "genres": [{'id': 28, 'name': 'Action'},
               {'id': 878, 'name': 'Science Fiction'},
               {'id': 12, 'name': 'Adventure'}],
    "poster_path": "/edv5CZvWj09upOsy2Y6IwDhK8bt.jpg"
}
data = fake_data

print (data["title"])
print (data["tagline"])
print (data["genres"])
print (data["poster_path"])
print(", ".join([genre["name"] for genre in data["genres"]]))
#                                                           ^
#                this parenthesis was missing in Jack's comment
```

```
Inception
Your mind is the scene of the crime.
[{'id': 28, 'name': 'Action'}, {'id': 878, 'name': 'Science Fiction'}, {'id': 12, 'name': 'Adventure'}]
/edv5CZvWj09upOsy2Y6IwDhK8bt.jpg
Action, Science Fiction, Adventure
```

Comment: @Lotus you can mark the answer as Accepted then :)